# How can I iterate through data?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: (path+args),
    type: "POST",
    success: function( data ){
        // do stuff with "data"
    }
});
```

If data looks like the following:

```
<div id="imageList">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

How can I iterate through data which has the divs?

Comment: you posted this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485749/how-can-i-loop-through-all-divs-by-id-in-jquery` couple of minutes ago

Comment: No, it's different. Look closely.

Comment: What data are you referring here??? div or div's value (which is not mentioned here)

Comment: The div itself which has class="image"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have control of what the server is returning, I'd probably send JSON back to the browser – something like:

```
[
    { url: "a.png" },
    { url: "b.png" }
]
```

...which makes it easy to do something like `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) data[i].url`.

That said, if you don't have control over what's coming back from the server, you can create a fragment with the returned data and use normal jQuery methods.

```
$(data).children('.image').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).children('img').attr('src');  // or whatever
});
```

This works because passing a string of HTML to jQuery creates a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), parsing the HTML in your string and creating a "mini-DOM".  The returned jQuery object selects the top-level element of that DOM (in this case, `div#imageList`), and you can traverse the fragment DOM freely.

In my example, I select the children of `#imageList` with class `image` and then iterate over each selected element.

Comment: Is the json method faster?

Comment: Absolutely.  Rule number one of working with the DOM: [The DOM is *very* slow.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11925491/201952)  Browsers have native JSON parsers (`JSON.parse()`), and pure JS `for` loops over arrays are very fast.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
$(data).children('div').each(function(){
$(this).doSomething();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$.each( $('#imageList'), function(i, imageList) {
   $('div', imageList).each(function() {

   });
})

or could use something like:

$("#imageList").children().each()
```